# understanding of some Luigi issues

Tags: python, error-handling, pipeline, luigi

Look at class ATask

```
class ATask(luigi.Task):
    config = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
         # Some Tasks maybe

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("A.txt")

    def run(self):
        with open("A.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("Complete")
```

Now look at class BTask

```
class BTask(luigi.Task):
    config = luigi.Parameter()

    def requires(self):
         return ATask(config = self.config)

    def output(self):
        return luigi.LocalTarget("B.txt")

    def run(self):
        with open("B.txt", "w") as f:
            f.write("Complete")
```

Question is there is a chance that while TaskA running and start write "A.txt" taskB will start before taskA finishing writing?

The second is that if I start execution like

```
luigi.build([BTask(config=some_config)], local_scheduler=True )
```

And if this pipilene fail inside - Could I somehow to know outside about this like return value of luigi.build or smth else?

Answer (score 1):

1. No, luigi won't start executing TaskB until TaskA has finished (ie, until it has finished writing the target file)
2. If you want to get a detailed response for `luigi.build` in case of error, you must pass an extra keyword argument: `detailed_summary=True` to build/run methods and then access the `summary_text`, this way:

```py
     luigi_run_result = luigi.build(..., detailed_summary=True)
     print(luigi_run_result.summary_text)
```

For details on that, please read [Response of luigi.build()/luigi.run()](https://luigi.readthedocs.io/en/stable/running_luigi.html#response-of-luigi-build-luigi-run) in Luigi documentation.

Also, you may be interested in this answer about how to access the error / exception: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33396642/3219121

Comment: Thank you, very useful for me indeed. But how, luigi will internally control starting of taskB? Because if "A.txt" will be already on hard drive before luigi.build - luigi will start taskB without starting taskA, as I know

Comment: luigi.build([Task(config=config)], local_scheduler=True, detailed_summary=True) and I got exception "unknown parameter detailed_summary". I didn't find in search such problems. Do you have idea what happened ?